# Changing the title name on the web browser tab?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer, internet-sites

I have an intranet portal and on the Browsers tab it shows "Home- Home".

Now I did edit the page title and set it to "X.Inc Intranet". But now it just shows "Home- X.Inc Intranet"

[image]

What else should I be editing to get this right?

Comment: What exact title do you wanna have on the tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint does this by default.  You can, however, override the page title with jQuery: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2007-jquery-to-fix-ugly-page-titles/

You could use this solution to create a custom page head control that includes your JavaScript to override the page title: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-add-javascript-meta-tags-and-css-styles-to-the-header-of-every-page/

Comment: Thanks for the links John! I wonder why Microsoft dint bother to address this..